# Remove the last character from dynamically generated string

Tags: php

I a trying to remove the last character in my string. I have seen many examples to do that but all the methods are removing my all '&' but i want only my last character '&' to be removed.

My string is :

> https://website.biz/get/#TYPE#?   partner_id=XXXXXXXX&api_password=XXXXXXXX&mobile_no=#NUMBER#&operator_code=#OPERATORID#&amount=#AMOUNT#&partner_request_id=#ORDERID#&circle=10&recharge_type=NORMAL&

The complete API is dynamic. I want to remove the last string '&' from this string. The above line is coming from my PHP code :

```
<td><?php $parameter = fetchAPIparameter($v6['api_id'],$v6['operator_type']);
    foreach ($parameter as $v7) {
       $pks = ($v7['parameter'].'='.$v7['result'].'&'); echo ($pks);
    } ?></td>
```

I have used `substr($pks,0,-1)` and `substr_replace($pks,"",-1)` and `rtrim` and `mb_substr` but all are removing the complete '&' from my API. Can you please help me what mistake i am doing.

Comment: Thats because you echo the string. Just build the string, remove last character, then echo.

Comment: have you tried trim() ?

Comment: Don't build your query string like that in the first place, use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a string in a variable then remove the last character.
The way you do it you remove the last character on each iteration which is not what you want.

```
<td><?php 
$parameter = fetchAPIparameter($v6['api_id'],$v6['operator_type']);
$pks = "";
foreach ($parameter as $v7) {
   $pks .= ($v7['parameter'].'='.$v7['result'].'&');  //here i am getting error
} 
echo substr($pks,0,-1);
?></td>
```

`.=` means it will append to the string.
`substr` will echo all but the last character.

Comment: I am getting the exact this but with an error `Notice: Undefined variable: pks `

Comment: Did you add the third line? `$pks = "";`

Comment: I didn't add. I got the output. Thanks a lot

Comment: The notice isn't harmful, it's just annoying. I generally always take care of them, but the only affect of them (in this case) is a **very very** slight performance decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Although it should work with `substr` if applied in the correct way, in your case it is better to prevent the last `&` from being added. For that you can use `implode`:

```
$parameter = fetchAPIparameter($v6['api_id'],$v6['operator_type']);
$pks=[];
foreach ($parameter as $v7) {
   $pks[] = $v7['parameter'].'='.$v7['result']; 
}
$pks = "https://website.biz/get/#TYPE#?" . implode("&", $pks);
echo $pks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this and use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($parameter as $v7) {
    $result[$v7['parameter']] = $v7['result'];
}

$pks = "https://website.biz/get/#TYPE#?" .  http_build_query($result);
```

This will build an array `$result` using the 'parameter' as the key and 'result' as the value. Then http_build_query will generate a URL-encoded query string.